# Build a static library for c++ which is internally dependent on third-party libraries

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, gnu, static-linking

I want to make a library say `libmyfoo.a` at a location `/home/my/library/libmyfoo.a`

And I want to use this static library in the simplest form as below:

Lets say this is **myProgram.cpp**

```
#include "AAA.h"

int main(void) {
    int x = 2;

    myFooFunction(x);

    return(0);
}
```

I want to run this as `g++ -std=c++11 -I/path/to/AAA.h myProgram.c -o myProgram -L/home/my/library/ -lmyfoo`

**Now:**
The `AAA.h` (and `AAA.cc`) are dependent on a third party framework/libraries, namely *gstreamer*, *protobuf* and *grpc*

The hierarchy at `/path/to/AAA.h` is

```
Makefile
AAA.h
AAA.cc
AAA.o
BBB(Folder)
    BBB.cc
    BBB.h
    BBB.o
```

The Makefile has the rule:

```
GOOGLEAPIS_GENS_PATH ?= $(HOME)/GOOGLE/googleapis/gens
GOOGLEAPIS_API_CCS = $(shell find $(GOOGLEAPIS_GENS_PATH)/google/api \
    -name '*.pb.cc')
GOOGLEAPIS_RPC_CCS = $(shell find $(GOOGLEAPIS_GENS_PATH)/google/rpc \
    -name '*.pb.cc')
GOOGLEAPIS_SPEECH_CCS = $(shell find \
    $(GOOGLEAPIS_GENS_PATH)/google/cloud/speech -name '*.pb.cc')
GOOGLEAPIS_LONGRUNNING_CCS = $(shell find \
    $(GOOGLEAPIS_GENS_PATH)/google/longrunning -name '*.pb.cc')
GOOGLEAPIS_CCS = $(GOOGLEAPIS_API_CCS) $(GOOGLEAPIS_RPC_CCS) \
    $(GOOGLEAPIS_LONGRUNNING_CCS) $(GOOGLEAPIS_SPEECH_CCS)


OBJS = ./BBB/BBB.o AAA.o

.PHONY: all
all: libmyfoo.a
libmyfoo.a: $(OBJS) $(GOOGLEAPIS_CCS:.cc=.o)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJS) $(GOOGLEAPIS_CCS:.cc=.o)
    ranlib $@
    echo "build final executable......"
```

This builds the `libmyfoo.a` with alot of `*.o` files in it.

**Problem:** When I am trying to run the `myProgram.cpp` as shown above it throws undefined reference to alot of things. That mean it is not getting linking correctly.

Now the `AAA.cc` and `BBB.cc` are dependent on grpc, protobuf and gstreamer as I said. So I linked those in `myProgram.cpp` as

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/path/to/AAA.h myProgram.c -o myProgram -L/home/my/library/ -lmyfoo -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -lgrpc++ -lgrpc -lgrpc++_reflection -lprotobuf -lpthread -lglib-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -ldl -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

And this **works absolutely fine**.

Can someone explain this why?
And also is it possible to run `myProgram.cpp` the way it is mentioned earlier i.e.  `g++ -std=c++11 -I/path/to/AAA.h myProgram.c -o myProgram -L/home/my/library/ -lmyfoo`

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a static library you use depends on shared libraries, you need to explicitly link your final binary against those shared libraries. The reason for that is that a static library is just a collection of object files, packed into an "ar" archive (that's what `.a` files are.) No information is stored about shared library dependencies.

Comment: I get that. And as you said, the shared libraries (`xyz.so`) are to be linked expilcitly. But is there a way I can make those third party (shared) libraries - > static? Is that even possible?

Comment: @RC0993 No. A shared library cannot be converted into a static one. You would need to build static versions of the needed libraries. In the case of gstreamer, this is nearly impossible. I tried it once, but you then need to explicitly instantiate all needed plugins in your code, and there's hundreds of them, with a very complex dependency structure. I spent about 5 days non-stop on this and gave up in the end.

Comment: Ohh, that's a great help. Apparently I was trying to accomplish the "nearly impossible" thing :P. In conclusion would you say there is nothing better to be done here in what I posted?

Comment: @RC0993 Depending on your use case, libvlc might be a better choice if your goal is to distribute a binary that doesn't need external media libraries. GStreamer is difficult to bundle with a binary package. For one of my projects, I switched from gstreamer to libvlc. It also can't be built as a static library (it has the same plugin issues as gstreamer), but it is easier to bundle its shared libraries.

Comment: I have a few constraints, so for now I would stick to the gstreamer here. but I will surely look for `libvlc` in coming projects if I have a room to shift. :) Thanks for all your help @NikosC